# Coverting row data into a line of string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I convert row data into a line of string as shown below. Thanks in advance.

**From this**

| Coffee | Milk | Juice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 5 | 10 |

**To This**

| Details |
| --- |
| Coffee: 15; Milk: 5; Juice: 10; |

I have tried using `TRANSLATE()` but its not getting anywhere close to what I want.

Comment: I'm so sorry for that, i had learned my mistakes, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: `CONCAT` is an option: `SELECT CONCAT('Coffee: ', Coffee, '; Milk: ', Milk, '; Juice: ', Juice) FROM ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with:

```
SELECT
'Coffee: '+ CAST(coffee as varchar(your_length)) +
'; Milk: ' + CAST(milk as varchar(your_length)) + 
'; Juice: ' + CAST(juice as varchar(your_length))
FROM example
```

Comment: It baffles me that a query that uses `varchar` with no length would be upvoted.  This habit is just a bug waiting to happen.  In SQL Server, the string data types should *always* be used with a length, because the default length varies by context and can introduce unexpected errors.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic way how to handle dynamic column names. They are not hard-coded.

XML, XQuery, and its FLWOR expression to the rescue.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Coffee INT, Milk INT, Juice INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (Coffee, Milk, Juice) VALUES
(15, 5, 10),
(25, 7, 18);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT p.ID
    , (
    SELECT * FROM @tbl AS c
    WHERE c.id = p.ID
    FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
).query('
    for $x in /root/r/*[local-name()!="ID"]
    return concat(local-name($x)[1], ":", $x/text()[1], ";")
').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Result
FROM @tbl AS p
GROUP BY p.ID;
```

**Output**

```
+----+------------------------------+
| ID |            Result            |
+----+------------------------------+
|  1 | Coffee:15; Milk:5; Juice:10; |
|  2 | Coffee:25; Milk:7; Juice:18; |
+----+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

A much better way to write this query uses `concat()`:

```
SELECT CONCAT('Coffee: ', coffee, '; Milk: ', milk, '; Juice: ', juice)
FROM example
```